# Get the time the message reached Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

The timestamp in the message meta for Kafka says the time the Kafka producer sent the message, but my objective is to extract the time the message reached the Kafka cluster. Is there any way to extract this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default Kafka will use the timestamp provided by the producer.

However, you can also make Kafka update the timestamp when it writes the record to the log by setting `message.timestamp.type` to `LogAppendTime` on your topic.

See the [topic configurations section](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#topicconfigs) in the documentation.